# Generic Data Record Cannot be cast to Avro

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, avro, mapper

I have recently run a **Sqoop** job and then used **AvroTools** to extract the schema of the avro files and then to compile it in to a **Java** class. Whenever I try to use the Avro object, I get the following ClassCastException:

> java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to
>   com.xxx.xxx.patient_avro.PatientAvro      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
>         at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
>     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to
>   com.xxx.xxx.patient_avro.PatientAvro      at
>   com.xxx.xxx.knn_mapreduce.KNNMapper.map(KNNMapper.java:28)        at
>   com.xxx.xxx.knn_mapreduce.KNNMapper.map(KNNMapper.java:14)        at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)       at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)       at
>   org.apache.hadoop.
>   mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)

My Mapper:

```
public class KNNMapper extends Mapper<AvroKey<PatientAvro>, NullWritable, LongWritable, PatientWritable> {

PatientWritable patient;
LongWritable providerKey;
Integer patientKey;
Integer lengthOfStay;
Integer msDrgGroup;
Integer age;

@Override
public void map(AvroKey<PatientAvro> patientAvro, NullWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {



    patientKey = patientAvro.datum().getPatientKey();
    lengthOfStay = patientAvro.datum().getLengthOfStay();
    msDrgGroup = patientAvro.datum().getMsDrg();
    age = patientAvro.datum().getAge();
    patient = new PatientWritable();
    patient.set(new Long(patientKey), new Double((double) lengthOfStay), new Double((double) msDrgGroup), new Double((double)age));

    providerKey = new LongWritable(patientAvro.datum().getProviderKey());
    context.write(providerKey, patient);
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the dependencies used in your pom.xml? And did you get this error in a normal execution or executing a MRUnit?

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop automatically creates the Java and the .avsc files. Are you creating them separately?. So if you just use the generated Java you should be fine.